# Is it okay to make a button appear in a table header after an action?

Tags: buttons, tables, data-tables, actions, fixed-header

I need assistance in deciding between two user experiences for handling tabular data.

Use Case: Users encounter a difficult-to-process column (the 2nd one in this instance) and they decide to split the values of this column into two separate columns, each with its own user-defined name.

**Option 1**

Default State: This is the initial view where users see a table loaded with various actions in the header, each applicable to all the data in the table.

Acquired State: After the user splits the column, ‘a new action’ button appears. This button is linked only to the two newly created columns. Using icons to show which columns are connected to this new button.

**Option 2**

Default state: Here, you'll see a table filled with various header actions applicable to all the tabular data. In addition, there's an action dedicated to a select few eligible columns. The number of available eligible columns is indicated here: [A new action (0)]. Upon clicking this button in default state, an empty state appears, guiding you on how to utilize it for data analysis.

Acquired state: After you execute the split action, an 'Acquired state' materializes showing a new dedicated button linked only to the two newly split columns. Iconography is used here to connect these columns to the button.

Which of these option you think would be easy to notice and process for users?

[image: attaching image containing option 1 and 2]

Comment: What is the use case? In what situation is it possible to split the contents of a column into multiple columns? This sounds like a x-y question to me. If it is possible to split the content, why isn't it already split?

Comment: The use case pertains to log usage in data space. Users can typically understand logs as they are ingested. However, on certain occasions, they need to divide the data into multiple columns for analytical purposes.